# How do I add -http-proxy to an android emulator launch from Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, react-native, charles-proxy

I have a local dev web server running on a machine sitting next to me.

I use a hosts file locally on my laptop to map an url to the machine and apparently the android emulator uses NAT and can't resolve the url.

I wanted to configure the emulator to use Charles Proxy for all Internet traffic so that it will go through my laptop and pick up my hosts file for name resolution.

The instructions [here](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/browser-and-system-configuration/) say I need to set -http-proxy.

How do I do that if I launch from Android Studio 2.0?

Answer (score 8):

Run emulator from command line

```
emulator -avd <avd name> -http-proxy ip:port

emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_23 -http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8888
```

Windows

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_23 -http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8888
```

BTW
I wasn't able to make a proxy work for me.

There other alternatives The best way to review Android HTTP connections:

1. OKHtttp Logging Interceptor - logs in logcat, good for Retrofit
2. Flipper https://fbflipper.com/ - nice UI and modern multiplatform approach
3. Network Profiler - build into Android Studio, but I never made it work
4. Stetho http://facebook.github.io/stetho - allows to display all android device/emulator requests/responses in Google chrome developer tools (deprecated but still works well)

Answer (score 5):

Open the Android emulator, go to mobile data settings, change the APN and insert there ip and port of your proxy.

From now on, all the data in/out of the emulator will go through your proxy.

[image: Settings]

[image: Mobile Networks]

[image: Mobile Networks Settings]

[image: APNs]

[image: Proxy]

Comment: I can't find such settings the Marshmallow emulator. Could you provide a more detailed guide or screenshots?

Comment: Which address should I use? I tried 10.0.2.2 and my lan address... neither one worked.

Comment: You must have a proxy set up on your pc, you said you're using a Charlie proxy, then you should put the ip address of that proxy.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Thanks for the helpful screenshots, solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried above steps but it was not coming. Finally the command prompt worked.

```
emulator -avd <avd name> -http-proxy http://CharlesIP address:8888/
```