# How to set proxy to android device emulator when launched from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

how can I set proxy configuration to my AVD from Android Studio?
I tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803553/how-do-i-add-http-proxy-to-an-android-emulator-launch-from-android-studio-2-0), but it seems not working...